# how to get the URL of the API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC site which has 4 layers:

1. UI
2. DAL
3. BLL
4. Services

In the services layer, I have all the WebApi controllers. I have referenced the Services layer in my UI layer.

This is the jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax(
{
  url : "api/albums",
  type: "POST",
  data: {} ,
  sucess:function(data){},
  error:function(e){}
})
```

Now I am getting a 404 Error for the above URL. I do agree it is quite obvious.

### My question is - What will be the URL of the service/API in this scenario?

API Controller:

```
public class AlbumsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return albums {  };
    }

     // GET api/values
    public void Post(Album album)
    {
        albums.Add(album);
    }
 }
```

WebAPi.config:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

After seeing a few answers, here I am adding inputs.

When I say `/api/albums`, it looks for a controller named api and tries to find an action named `Albums` because in the UI layer, the routes are configured `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. I am trying to call the API controller which is present in the services layer, and this layer is referenced in the UI layer.

Comment: Without the controller code its anyones guess. You need to show the controller's class name, the method signature you are calling, any attributes you have listed on that method, any attributes you have listed on the class, and your url mapping code in the `webapiconfig.cs`. With that information we could take a guess as to what the url should be.

Comment: @Igor controller added

Comment: @Chetan you can get the answer from your route setup in your web api project. it will be -  `routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",`  or something along those lines. so may be your web api host address such as `localhost\someprojectname.api\yourcontroller\youraction`

Comment: **it looks for an controller named api** - actually it _looks for a controller with a name `Albums`_.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh.. In the UI layer the routes are configured as `{controller}/{action}/{id}` & the controller that I am trying to call is present the WebApi Service layer

Comment: whatever it is, and wherever it might be - you identify resources through urls,and they are uniform.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh.. how the route engine will detect in the current call api is not a controller name but trying to refer the api controller that is present in the dll of the service layer

Answer (score 1):

Here you have hardcoded an url:

```
url : "api/MyControllerName",
```

That's bad, and should never be done. You should use url helpers.

So in your ASP.NET MVC Layout, you could use an Url helper to generate the proper url:

```
<script>
    window.myUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Albums" })';
</script>
```

and then use this when making your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url : window.myUrl,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
{
  url : "api/Albums/",
  type: "GET",
  sucess:function(data){},
  error:function(e){}
})
```

- url = api/Controller name (without out the suffix controller)
- Type = GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE
- Data = only possible on actions other than GET

Comment: Why should I add GET in the url

Comment: That is the name of your method in the controller you defined. You can name your method anything but the url should point to that method unless you specify it as the default action in your mapping that if you do not supply method it should default to method Get.

Comment: This is WebAPI, not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
 url : "api/MyControllerName/ActionName"
```

In this parameter you should also pass Action Method Name ,Currently you are getting 404 error because probably by default Index method is getting Called which may not exist in your controller, So try by pass ActionMethod Name